# Gem installed but 'command not found'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, terminal, rbenv

I've installed a Ruby gem called wordmove to work with pushing and pulling my Wordpress sites but when I run wordmove commands I get the error command not found. I've done some research and I haven't come up with much, I've come to the conclusion based on what I've seen that my Ruby install is messed up.

I ran `echo "$PATH"` from my root and it returned the following:

```
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/brettgolding/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/user/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

I am a noob with the terminal so have no idea how to clean this mess up.

Comment: Did you watch the output of `gem install wordmove` and verify it loaded successfully? Check the output of `gem list` and make sure it's in the list.

Comment: It would be a wise idea to post the exact error output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you're working with `rbenv`. According to its [README](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-rehash), you should run `rbenv rehash` after installing any gems that have an executable command. Also, run it anytime you install a new Ruby version.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unaware of your issue.